# Where can I find groups, items, etc deletion logs in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, logging, site-deletion

Is there any way to knows elements that have been deleted on sharepoint 2010?

I'd like track any delete operation from any user (moss too).

Answer (score 1):

Check if your auditing is enabled.

1. Navigate to `Site Settings → Site Collection Administration → Site collection features → Choose “Reporting” →` See if it is activated else Press “Activate”.
2. Navigate to `Site Settings → Site Collection Administration → Site collection audit settings → Check if “Deleting or restoring items”` is checked else check it → Click “OK”.
3. Navigate to `Site Settings → Site Collection Administration → Audit
   log reports → Deletions →` Open the generated report in Microsoft
   Excel.

Comment: If the deletion is made by Powershell?

Comment: I don't think audit logs are just tied to UI actions but more to the actual data in the database, so any actions (UI or Powershell) should get recorded. However, it would be interesting to see what it takes as user information when it records a deletion using powershell (I assume it would be the sharepoint account)

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question. If I delete an item o group by Powershell, is possible to recorver it?

Comment: Items deleted by powershell do not go to the recycle bin, so will not be available for recovery